# ADF : Scaling image to button size

Tags: imagebutton, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am new to ADF programming(JDeveloper).Kindly help me with this basic Question.
 I would like to have an Image button with Image (say 200*200 pixel size) scaled to a small button size. I used an Image Button(Adf Faces) and adjusted its Height and Width parameters in Style-> Dimensions but the image never shrinks to a small size
        height:2px; width:2px;  margin:150px;

I also tried to use a normal Button(ADf Faces) and then added an Icon image to it. Here I can decrease the button size as a whole and so the images gets truncated :-(. Please tell me work around with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use commandImageLink - http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/commandImageLink.jspx

Or use an imaging software to resize the image and then assign it to the button.

Comment: There is ImageLink in JDeveloper 11.1.2.1.0 and it doesn't have any "Geometry of Container" attribute..Ya Re-sizing image is one option but I am hoping to find some Adf way to get about this issue